# how to show my clicked row from my JTable connection to my MS access data Base to JTextFields

Tags: java, swing, ms-access

I have program which i show MS Access Database row and column to my JTable and if click a cell from that JTable all data will be shown to it respective JTextField.  Here are my codes.

```
    public void reloadData() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException 
    {        

            columnNames.clear();
            data.clear();

            String DBPAD = "sourceFolder/employeeTable1.mdb";
            String DB = "jdbc:ucanaccess://" + DBPAD;   

            con1x = DriverManager.getConnection(DB);
            st1x = con1x.createStatement();
            rs1x = st1x.executeQuery("Select * FROM employeeTable1");
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs1x.getMetaData();
            int column = rsmd.getColumnCount();                 

            columnNames.addElement("Employee Name");              
            columnNames.addElement("Employee Address");            
            columnNames.addElement("Employee Marital Status");
            columnNames.addElement("Employee Date of Membership");
            columnNames.addElement("Employee Blood Type");
            columnNames.addElement("Employment Status");                
            columnNames.addElement("Employee Gender");
            columnNames.addElement("Employee Date Of Birth");
            columnNames.addElement("Employee Age");
            columnNames.addElement("Beginning Capital");
            columnNames.addElement("Gross Salary");
            columnNames.addElement("Salary Deductions");
            columnNames.addElement("Net Salary");

            while(rs1x.next()) 
            {
                Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>(column);
                for(int i=1; i<=column; i++) 
                {                   
                     row.addElement(rs1x.getObject(i));
                }
                data.addElement(row);               
            }   


            try
            {
                mainTableJTableCoop.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener()
                {
                   public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) 
                   {    
                      String employeeName = (mainTableJTableCoop.getValueAt(mainTableJTableCoop.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString());
                      endrollNameFields.setText(employeeName);                  

                      String employeeAddress = (mainTableJTableCoop.getValueAt(mainTableJTableCoop.getSelectedRow(), 1).toString());
                      endrollAddressFields.setText(employeeAddress);

                      String employeeMaritalSatatus = (mainTableJTableCoop.getValueAt(mainTableJTableCoop.getSelectedRow(), 2).toString());
                      maritalstatusFields.setText(employeeMaritalSatatus);

                      String employeeDateOfMembership = (mainTableJTableCoop.getValueAt(mainTableJTableCoop.getSelectedRow(), 3).toString());
                      dateOfMembershipFields.setText(employeeDateOfMembership);

                      String employeeBloodType = (mainTableJTableCoop.getValueAt(mainTableJTableCoop.getSelectedRow(), 4).toString());
                      bloodTypeFields.setText(employeeBloodType);

                      String employeeEmploymentStatus = (mainTableJTableCoop.getValueAt(mainTableJTableCoop.getSelectedRow(), 5).toString());
                      endrollEmployeestatusFields.setText(employeeEmploymentStatus);

                      String employeeGender = (mainTableJTableCoop.getValueAt(mainTableJTableCoop.getSelectedRow(), 6).toString());
                      genderFields.setText(employeeGender);

                      String dateOfBirth = (mainTableJTableCoop.getValueAt(mainTableJTableCoop.getSelectedRow(), 7).toString());
                      birthDateFields.setText(dateOfBirth); 

                      String employeeAge = (mainTableJTableCoop.getValueAt(mainTableJTableCoop.getSelectedRow(), 8).toString());
                      ageFields.setText(employeeAge);   

                      String beginningCapital = (mainTableJTableCoop.getValueAt(mainTableJTableCoop.getSelectedRow(), 9).toString());
                      beginningCapitalFields.setText(beginningCapital);

                      String grossSalary = (mainTableJTableCoop.getValueAt(mainTableJTableCoop.getSelectedRow(), 10).toString());
                      grossSalaryFields.setText(grossSalary);

                      String deductions = (mainTableJTableCoop.getValueAt(mainTableJTableCoop.getSelectedRow(), 11).toString());
                      salaryDeductionFields.setText(deductions);

                      String netSalary = (mainTableJTableCoop.getValueAt(mainTableJTableCoop.getSelectedRow(), 12).toString());
                      netSalaryFields.setText(netSalary);                
                   }
                });              
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }


    }
```

My Codes looks OK but every time I click a row from my JTable which is connected to my MS access database the information that appears in my JTextFields are always the data from the first row, even if i click the second, third row. Any suggestion to achieved my desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Without a runnable example is difficult to 100% sure, my first thought is, you shouldn't be adding another `ListSelectionListener` to the `JTable` when `reloadData` is called.  This will add ANOTHER listener every time you call this method, accumulatively, which could have some interesting side effects and possibly degrade your program.

Also `ListSelectionListener` may be notified twice of change in selection, once when the selection is deselected (what ever was currently selected) and once when the new selection occurs.

You should check the state of the `getValueIsAdjusting` of the `ListSelectionEvent` to determine if the another event might be delivered or not

```
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) 
{   
    if (!event.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
        int selectedRow = mainTableJTableCoop.getSelectedRow();
```

See [How to Write a List Selection Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) for more details.

Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 0):

for now i would say try using a print statement to see the values that this "mainTableJTableCoop.getSelectedRow()" returns each time your event handler receives an event, this can get you started in figuring out where the problem is coming from.